# UnitOfWork Exception: Can't close, connection is in state Connecting

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, dbcontext, dispose

in my project i'm using

.NET 6
Blazor-Server-Side : V6.0.10
EF-Core PostgreSQL: V 6.0.4
and a UnitOfWork pattern.

On
the index.razor page i'm loading some data from the database this take a few seconds.

[image]

In this time when i leave the razor page for example to login with discord the page trigger the Dispose function fom my unitofworker class and i get the error message : **Can't close, connection is in state Connecting.**

[image]
This happen only when i leave the razor page before the data are loaded.

Here is my unitofworker class:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly FMDataContext _context;
    
    // SOME REPOSITORYS

    private bool _disposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
            if (disposing)
                _context.Dispose();
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

**Someone an idea how to fix this issue? How can dispose the dbcontext in connecting state?**

This code can fix the issue but is this correct to dispose the context only when not in connection state?

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!this.disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_context.Database.GetDbConnection().State != ConnectionState.Connecting)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    this.disposed = true;
}
```

Comment: can you try this 'await LoadLastOffers();' in OnAfterRenderAsync method. It seems you forgot to add await ?

Comment: What you posted isn't a Unit-of-Work implementation. A DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work. All changes are kept in memory and persisted when `SaveChanges` is called *once* right before the DbContext is disposed. If `SaveChanges` isn't called, they're discarded along with the DbContext. Calling `SaveChanges` twice in the same method breaks UoW because it's no longer impossible to revert the first changes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The question is about to solve the problem that an InvalidOperationException is thrown in a Dispose method, not a conversation about what is or isn't a unit-of-work implementation.

Comment: @Kerberos and that is caused by the misuse of DbContext. There are several similar SO questions with problems caused by misunderstanding what EF Core is and just slapping a badly written "unit of work" on top of it, breaking it. There are several problems in this code, starting from this UoW that disposes a singleton DbContext and a `LoadLastOffers` that isn't awaited. The docs clearly explain how to handle scoped services, including EF Core,  in Blazor Server

Comment: @Kerberos such "units of work" or "repositories" appear very frequently in similar questions. The way to fix the problems is to fix the problematic code. There's no magic switch that will make misbehaving code run correctly